# MATLAB: Block matrix multiplying without loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, transpose, scientific-computing

I have a block matrix `[A B C...]` and a matrix *D* (all 2-dimensional). *D* has dimensions y-by-y, and *A, B, C*, etc are each z-by-y. Basically, what I want to compute is the matrix `[D*(A'); D*(B'); D*(C');...]`, where *X*' refers to the transpose of *X*. However, I want to accomplish this without loops for speed considerations.

I have been playing with the reshape command for several hours now, and I know how to use it in other cases, but this use case is different from the other ones and I cannot figure it out. I also would like to avoid using multi-dimensional matrices if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, a loop is probably the best way to do it. In my image-processing work I found a well-written loop that takes advantage of Matlab's JIT compiler is often *faster* than all the extra overhead of manipulating the data to be able to use a vectorised operation. A loop like this:

```
[m n] = size(A);
T = zeros(m, n);
AT = A';
for ii=1:m:n
    T(:, ii:ii+m-1) = D * AT(ii:ii+m-1, :);
end
```

contains only built-in operators and the bare minimum of copying, and given the JIT is going to be hard to beat. Even if you want to factor in interpreter overhead it's still only a single statement with no functions to consider.

The "loop-free" version with extra faffing around and memory copying, is to [split the matrix](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and iterate over the blocks with [a hidden loop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
blksize = size(D, 1);
blkcnt = size(A, 2) / blksize;
blocks = mat2cell(A, blksize, repmat(blksize,1,blkcnt));
blocks = cellfun(@(x) D*x', blocks, 'UniformOutput', false);
T = cell2mat(blocks);
```

Of course, if you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox, you can also [cheat horribly](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
T = blockproc(A, size(D), @(x) D*x.data');
```

Comment: It's a component of an assignment though, and I am not allowed to use loops.

Comment: @user2258552 Ah, fair enough. You should state that clearly in the question. Might also be worth pointing out to whoever set the assignment that ["for speed considerations" really isn't as valid as it once was](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/) ;)

Comment: I'm sure he knows, he's a leader in the field of matrix computations. I think it was more for pedagogical purposes that he asked us to do this. There is a way to do this with reshape only without loops, which I have decided not to post because he might reuse similar problem in future years.

Answer (score 1):

### Prospective approach & Solution Code

Given:

- `M` is the block matrix `[A B C...]`, where each `A`, `B`, `C` etc. are of size `z x y`. Let the number of such matrices be `num_mat` for easy reference later on.
  If those matrices are concatenated along the columns, then `M` would be of size `z x num_mat*y`.
- `D` is the matrix to be multiplied with each of those matrices `A`, `B`, `C` etc. and is of size `y x y`.

Now, as stated in the problem, the output you are after is `[D*(A'); D*(B'); D*(C');...]`, i.e. the multiplication results being concatenated along the rows.
If you are okay with those multiplication results to be concatenated along the columns instead i.e. `[D*(A') D*(B') D*(C') ...]`,
you can achieve the same with some reshaping and then performing the
matrix multiplications for the entire `M` with `D` and thus have a vectorized no-loop approach. Thus, to get such a matrix multiplication result, you can do -

```
mults = D*reshape(permute(reshape(M,z,y,[]),[2 1 3]),y,[]);
```

But, if you HAVE to get an output with the multiplication results being concatenated along the `rows`, you need to do some more reshaping like so -

```
out = reshape(permute(reshape(mults,y,z,[]),[1 3 2]),[],z);
```

---

### Benchmarking

This section covers benchmarking codes comparing the proposed **vectorized approach** against a naive **JIT powered loopy approach** to get the desired output. As discussed earlier, depending on how the output array must hold the multiplication results, you can have two cases.

**Case I: Multiplication results concatenated along the columns**

```
%// Define size paramters and then define random inputs with those
z = 500; y = 500; num_mat = 500;
M = rand(z,num_mat*y);
D = rand(y,y);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('---------------------------- With loopy approach')
tic
out1 = zeros(z,y*num_mat);
for k1 = 1:y:y*num_mat
    out1(:,k1:k1+y-1) = D*M(:,k1:k1+y-1).'; %//'
end
toc, clear out1 k1

disp('---------------------------- With proposed approach')
tic
mults = D*reshape(permute(reshape(M,z,y,[]),[2 1 3]),y,[]);
toc
```

**Case II: Multiplication results concatenated along the rows**

```
%// Define size paramters and then define random inputs with those
z = 500; y = 500; num_mat = 500;
M = rand(z,num_mat*y);
D = rand(y,y);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('---------------------------- With loopy approach')
tic
out1 = zeros(y*num_mat,z);
for k1 = 1:y:y*num_mat
    out1(k1:k1+y-1,:) = D*M(:,k1:k1+y-1).'; %//'
end
toc, clear out1 k1

disp('---------------------------- With proposed approach')
tic
mults = D*reshape(permute(reshape(M,z,y,[]),[2 1 3]),y,[]);
out2 = reshape(permute(reshape(mults,y,z,[]),[1 3 2]),[],z);
toc
```

**Runtimes**

Case I:

```
---------------------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 3.889852 seconds.
---------------------------- With proposed approach
Elapsed time is 3.051376 seconds.
```

Case II:

```
---------------------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 3.798058 seconds.
---------------------------- With proposed approach
Elapsed time is 3.292559 seconds.
```

**Conclusions**

The runtimes suggest about a good `25% speedup` with the proposed vectorized approach! So, hopefully this works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get A, B, and C from a bigger matrix you can do this, assuming the bigger matrix is called X:

```
A = X(:,1:y)
B = X(:,y+1:2*y)
C = X(:,2*y+1:3*y)
```

If there are N such matrices, the best way is to use reshape like:

F = reshape(X, x,y,N)

Then use a loop to generate a new matrix I call it F1 as:

```
F1=[];
for n=1:N
   F1 = [F1 F(:,:,n)'];
end
```

Then compute F2 as:

```
F2 = D*F1;
```

and finally get your result as:

```
R = reshape(F2,N*y,x)
```

**Note**: this for loop does not slow you down as it is just to reformat the matrix and the multiplication is done in matrix form.

Comment: Okay, I realize I was unclear in my post. I do not actually have just matrices A, B, and C; the horizontal size of my matrix is variable, that is there may be many such matrices (the dimension of each, and of D, is always the same though).